# Interface builder and memory management

Tags: iphone

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlate UITextField *userName;
```

this property is to connect with TextField in IB.

1. Can we write `[userName release]` in `dealloc` to free the memory or it will be handled by IB.
2. Can i write `@property(nonatomic, copy)IBOutlate UITextField *userName;`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to declare your outlet as assign, rather than retain. This works for anything other than a top-level object (ie, all lower-level views are retained by their superview, so you don't have to worry about it):

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UITextField *username;
```